# Try catch private method phpunit symfony

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have the following code:

```
public function addSomething($paramDto) {
   try {
       $this->privateMethod($param);
   } catch(\Exception $e) {
       return ['error' => true, 'messages' => [$e->getMessage()]];
   }
   return ['error' => false, 'messages' => 'success'];
}

private function privateMethod($param) {
    if(!$param) {
        throw new \Exception('errorMessage');
    }
}
```

**I'm trying to test the addSomething method, what the catch block returns, I don't want to test the private method.**

```
 public function testAddSomethingThrowError($paramDto) {
    $param = \Mockery::mock('MyEntity');

    $method = new \ReflectionMethod(
        'MyService', 'privateMethod'
    );

    $method->setAccessible(TRUE);

    $this->expectException(\Exception::class);
    $this->getMyService()
        ->shouldReceive($method->invoke($param)
        ->withAnyArgs()
        ->andThrow(\Exception::class);
     $this->getMyService()->addSomething($paramDto);
 }
```

The thing is that if i run the test, it coverages the private method in the if statement and returns the exception, but the catch method in my addSomething method is not covered, actually it does not cover the addSomething method at all.

I am using the sebastian bergmann phpunit framework.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you even want to test private methods? Unit tests should test public interface of classes and that way private ones are tested indirectly. Private methods are there only to make your code clean.

Comment: I don't want to test the private method, I want to assert the message returned in the catch block.

Comment: You want to "assert if the public method is returning the message that it is indeed returning". There's no sense in doing that. Consider your tested class as a blackbox without possibility to check its source. Then make tests according to how to want it to work using its public interface.

Comment: Oh, i see. I didn't know that. Thanks for the quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer should be Jakub Matczak's answer:

"You want to "assert if the public method is returning the message that it is indeed returning". There's no sense in doing that. Consider your tested class as a blackbox without possibility to check its source. Then make tests according to how to want it to work using its public interface. "